How to check if WASAPI audio device is LSB or MSB format
I have an audio device using 32 bit data with 24 bit alignment and I am not sure how to determine if its LSB or MSB using the WASAPI IAudioClient interface.
I can retrieve WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE for format information such as wBitsPerSample and wValidBitsPerSample, but there doesn't seem to be a field for endianess.
With the ASIO audio interface there is the ASIOSampleType enum that indicates LSB or MSB. Is there something equivalent with WASAPI and if not do I just assume the architecture endianess?
I could not find this information in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/extensible-wave-format-descriptors
Thank you!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksmedia/ns-ksmedia-waveformatextensible: "If wValidBitsPerSample is less than Format.wBitsPerSample, the valid bits (the actual PCM data) are left-aligned within the container. The unused bits in the least-significant portion of the container should be set to zero."
